# Few people vs Some people

Tags: sentence-construction, quantifiers

I got a sentence where I was asked to correct/improve it by choosing one of the given options. I was sure of using "Few" instead of "Some" with people but it turned out that I was wrong. I thought using  "Few people" was correct. The question sentence is below:

> **Some people has all** the luck even when they did not try very hard.

a) Some people have all
b) Few people have all

Please help me get rid of this confusion between "some / few people". Same goes with "few children/ some children". I think "few" has to do something with negative meaning sentences and "some" with positive sense making sentences?

Comment: The quoted phrase is ungrammatical (perhaps that's the point), and, the use of *when they* ***did*** is unidiomatic in the context of the sentence—it should be *when they* ***do not***.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes, I do know that part is wrong. It should have been " when they do not try..".. but what about the " some people have" and " Few people have " part? I heard from someone that " Some people have all the luck" is idiomatic and hence it's the correct one here?? Is that so? Please enlighten me. Thank you